# How do I solve this error code in R data panel model

Tags: r, economics

Im trying to run this code but I have not been successful for a fixed-effect model in R.

this are my variables

```
y <- cbind(tfpch)
x <- cbind(EI, LP, INFA)
```

This is the code and the error

> fixed<-plm(y~x,data = mydata,index = c("ID", "t"), model="within")
>   Error in class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "pseries") : 
>     invalid to set the class to matrix unless the dimension attribute is of length 2 (was 0)

Im looking how to fix this issue but none of the solutions offered here the work so far.

Comment: Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. In particular, please [edit] your question to include the output of the R commands `dput(tfpch); dput(EI); dput(LP); dput(INFA)`. (You may want to wrap the variables in `head()` if your data is large

Comment: It is not clear what variables you are using. From the information you gave, it seems that you are not using the formula correctly. What are the columns of mydata?

Comment: Many thanks for your help, im sorry im a newbie in R I get the point that you are making but I don't know how to use the head() function.

Comment: @DJJ The columns of my data are ID(name of the firm), t(year), EI(energy intensity -independent variable, LP(labour productivity - independent variable, INFA(Investment in fixed assets - independent variable, TFPCH (total factor of productivity change -dependent variable).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with the information you provided. I'll refer you to the plm documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/plm.pdf). But I feel that you are skipping too many steps and suggest you take to some time to read [this](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf). You can check the chapter on statistical model to learn how to use formula.